# Regex expression to match all cucumber steps and grab double quotes

Tags: ruby, regex, cucumber

As some background, I am attempting to write a generalized step that will match steps such as

```
When I "click" on "send" button
When I "press" on that "clear" thingy
When I "select" some kind of "money" maker
```

and give me what is in quotes.

Optimally the step will look something like

```
When(/regex here/) do |action, target|
   #do something here
end
```

I have tried`(.*)"(.*)"(.*)"(.*)"(.*)` and it does work but would require me to write the step such as

```
When(/(.*)"(.*)"(.*)"(.*)"(.*)/) do |unused, action, unused, target, unused|
   #do something here
end
```

another side effect is the entire step in the .feature file becomes highlighted, which is minor but would be nice to know exactly what is being grabbed, which is what is in double quotes.

What would be the Regex expression to accomplish this goal?

Comment: If you have a string then you can use the scan method to and get all matches with the regexp /"(.*?)"/

Comment: Wouldn't this force me to first use a (.*) expression which would match to absolutely every step?

Comment: The scan method looks for every single match, not only the first.

Comment: First, I wouldn't try to create a mega step that does so many things. Second, I wouldn't describe the how in the step. Instead of 'I click on the send button', 'I send the message' or 'I submit the order'. The reason is that I want to identify behavior, not the technology that implements the behavior.

Comment: I would agree but upper management wants steps to also be requirements which means understanding how the application itself works on a lower level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `[^"]` to match anything except `"` characters and only specify the groups you want to capture. For example:

```
When(/"([^"]*)"[^"]*"([^"]*)"/) do |action, target|
   #do something here
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Again this is minor but I seem to have lost syntax highlighting. Also if I were to add a third quoted item, what would the regex look for that? My guess is /"([^"]*)"[^"]*"([^"]*)"[^"]*"([^"]*)/

Comment: @AlejandroHuerta You probably want to include a final `"`. e.g. `/"([^"]*)"[^"]*"([^"]*)"[^"]*"([^"]*)"/`